# How to select dropdown while scripting in appium

Tags: selenium, appium

I am using `Selenium Webdriver` with `Java and Appium` to automate a mobile application, I have 1 field where I need to select a value its not typically a drop down. Manually when we select, we need to click on the element and scroll and select a value. I tried using,

`driver.scrollToExact("8").click();`

but this is not working.

Can you please help me on this.

Comment: whats your implementation of `scrollToExact` here?

Answer (score 0):

on my understandings of questions
1) if you are in native app then use xpath,
2) if you are in web view try using SELECT method.